# Elements generated by ng-repeat cannot be acted on

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a page where a list of languages are (should be!) presented with previous user selections and then he/she can change the selected languages.

To do this I have prepared the following code:

```
 ...

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="One_Lang in Languages_List.Languages">
            <td align="center">
                <input id="{{One_Lang.code}}" ng-click="Handle_Language_Select(One_Lang.code)" type="checkbox" style="width:20px; height:20px;margin:5px 20px 5px 20px">
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="max-width:200px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                {{One_Lang.name}}
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="max-width:300px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                ({{One_Lang.nativeName}})
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

  ...
```

Getting something like the following:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ngRepeat: One_Lang in Languages_List.Languages --><tr ng-repeat="One_Lang in Languages_List.Languages" class="ng-scope">
            <td align="center">
                <input id="AB" ng-click="Handle_Language_Select(One_Lang.code)" type="checkbox" style="width:20px; height:20px;margin:5px 20px 5px 20px">
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="max-width:200px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;" class="ng-binding">
                Abkhaz
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="max-width:300px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;" class="ng-binding">
                (аҧсуа)
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: One_Lang in Languages_List.Languages --><tr ng-repeat="One_Lang in Languages_List.Languages" class="ng-scope">
            <td align="center">
                <input id="AA" ng-click="Handle_Language_Select(One_Lang.code)" type="checkbox" style="width:20px; height:20px;margin:5px 20px 5px 20px">
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="max-width:200px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;" class="ng-binding">
                Afar
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="max-width:300px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;" class="ng-binding">
                (Afaraf)
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: One_Lang in Languages_List.Languages --><tr ng-repeat="One_Lang in Languages_List.Languages" class="ng-scope">
            <td align="center">
                <input id="AF" ng-click="Handle_Language_Select(One_Lang.code)" type="checkbox" style="width:20px; height:20px;margin:5px 20px 5px 20px">
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="max-width:200px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;" class="ng-binding">
                Afrikaans
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="max-width:300px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;" class="ng-binding">
                (Afrikaans)
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <!-- Etc... -->
        
    </tbody>

</table>
```

(this is just a section of the table).

My problem is when I try to check those languages that were previously selected by the user. I tried (for instance) `document.getElementById("AA").checked = true;` (this would be the second language in the list) and I get an error stating that `TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null`. My guess is that this element ("AA") is still not known to the DOM. Tried also to have this within `$( document ).ready(function() {...});` with the same result.

Comment: previous selected value is in which variable? means are your storing those vales somewhere?

Comment: Indeed. I have a variable within the controller that holds the list (array) of all the languages that were previously selected. I can check the solution suggested by @AndyChen (see below) but, even if it works, I would like to know why I'm getting that error.

Comment: Approach is wrong for angular app. Use the view model data from within your controllers to check/monitor state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ng-checked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) on your checkbox, instead of manipulate by document.getElementById() :

**Update for document ready error explain :**

What you what to access is after angular compile, when document ready there is only uncompiled angular syntax on your document, as @charlietfl comment, document.ready is useless in angular.

```
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="One_Lang in Languages_List.Languages">
   <td align="center">
    <input id="{{One_Lang.code}}" ng-checked="userSelectPrevious===One_Lang.code" ng-click="Handle_Language_Select(One_Lang.code)" type="checkbox" style="width:20px; height:20px;margin:5px 20px 5px 20px">
   </td>
   ........
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Yeah, thought about this alternative, but would like to understand why I'm getting the error. Is it what I suspect(i.e. document not really ready, even when the `$( document ).ready(function() {...})` fires)?

Comment: @FDavidov *document.ready* is virtually useless in angular pages. Angular manipulates and constructs a significant part of the DOM after it has fired

Comment: @FDavidov  charlietfl is totally correct. As per angular lifecycle it works on lazily on page..so the jQuery code gets evaluated before you angular code render the DOM

Comment: Thanks guys for the answer and clarifications.

Comment: Andy ... document.getElementById() in controller will fail also when controller runs if used immediately. DOM code should not be used in controllers at all. What should be done in controller is monitor the data that is bound to the view

Comment: @charlietfl you are right, it should not use immidiately when controller runs, modify as your suggest.

Comment: Well.... The proposed solution does not work. I added `ng-checked="This_Lang_was_Selected(One_Lang.code)"`, where This_Lang_was_Selected(One_Lang.code) returns true/false depending if the language was previously selected or not. The function is not even invoked (deployed a breakpoint and nothing). I should add that I have an array holding the selected languages, and it needs to be scanned to check if the current language was previously selected or not.

Comment: Just found this working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TUdlKMggk3PR4tyHpNBP?p=preview). Not sure why my case is not working...

Comment: Solved!!!!! the addition now looks as follows: `ng-checked="{{This_Lang_was_Selected(One_Lang.code)}}"` meaning that the double-curly brackets were missing and hence evaluation was not being triggered.